# Group By for rows of one column only

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use Group By for the rows of one column only, let me explain how.

**My Query:-**

```
   SELECT
   m.name AS brand,
   opv.name AS model,
   opv.product_condition AS condition,
   (AVG(opv.final_price + opv.overhead_cost)) AS cost,
   opv.product_color AS color,
   COUNT(m.name) as quantity
   FROM `order` o
   JOIN order_veri AS ov
     ON o.order_id = ov.order_fk
   JOIN order_prod_veri AS opv
     ON ov.order_fk = opv.order_id
   JOIN product AS p
     ON opv.product_id = p.product_id
   JOIN manufacturer AS m
     ON p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
   GROUP  BY model,
             product_condition
```

This is the data I get:-

```
  Brand       |    Model           |    Cost    |    Condition    |  Color   |     Quantity    

  -------------------------------------------------------
  Apple       |    iPhone 5        |    $50.95  |     Used        |  Black   |     2
  Blackberry  |    Blackberry 9900 |    $22.98  |     Used        |  Black   |     2
  Samsung     |    Galaxy S        |    $16.92  |     Used        |  White   |     2
  HTC         |    Rhyme           |    $60.42  |     New         |  Red     |     2
  Google      |    Google Nexus    |    $72.24  |     New         |  Blue    |     2
  Motorola    |    Razr            |    $9.68   |     Used        |  Silver  |     2
  Apple       |    iPad Air        |    $2.74   |     New         |  Silver  |     1
```

**This is how I want to get the data (or how I want it to display):-**

```
  Brand       |    Model           |    Cost    |    Condition    |  Color   |     Quantity    

  -------------------------------------------------------
  Apple       |    iPhone 5        |    $50.95  |     Used        |  Black   |     2
  Apple       |    iPhone 5        |    $50.95  |     Used        |  White   |     

  Blackberry  |    Blackberry 9900 |    $22.98  |     Used        |  Black   |     3
  Blackberry  |    Blackberry 9900 |    $22.98  |     Used        |  White   |     
  Blackberry  |    Blackberry 9900 |    $22.98  |     Used        |  Black   |     

  HTC         |    Rhyme           |    $60.42  |     New         |  Red     |     2
  HTC         |    Rhyme           |    $60.42  |     New         |  Black   |     

  Google      |    Google Nexus    |    $72.24  |     New         |  Blue    |     2
  Google      |    Google Nexus    |    $72.24  |     New         |  Black   |     

  Motorola    |    Razr            |    $9.68   |     Used        |  Silver  |     2
  Motorola    |    Razr            |    $9.68   |     Used        |  White   |     2

  Apple       |    iPad Air        |    $2.74   |     New         |  Silver  |     1
```

Note how the price remains the same but there are now instead additional rows depending on the quantity which display the attributes of the same **Model**.

**What I want to achieve here:-**

Now in the color column, I am not getting the different color variations for each model due to grouping. For example, the quantity of **iPhone 5** in first row is 5 but it's showing the color for just the first in those 5.

Similarly, **Model** in the second row is **Blackberry 9900**, and the quantity is 2 but it's showing the color for 1 of them only due to grouping when they both are in two different colors (white and black).

So what I would like to ask is that is it possible to group just the cost using GROUP BY?

Please let me know if you would like to clarify something or provide a better explanation of what I want to achieve here.

Comment: Are you saying, for example, you should have two rows for `Blackberry 9900`, one for each color?  I think you need to add `opv.product_color` to your group by.  I really hate that MySQL lets you even do this.

Comment: @Andrew Exactly, but when I do that, I don't get the average cost and instead I get their individual costs. I want the cost to remain the average cost in both rows.

Comment: Confused. It sounds like you're saying that you have 2 total blackberry 9000s, and you want to show two for both black and white? That doesn't make sense.  Can you show us some raw data and what you want?

Comment: @Andrew updated my question, please have a look. Hope it's less confusing now.

Comment: How many bb 9900s of each color do you actually have?

Comment: Wow. Can I order that iPad Air? looks like a great price :-) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from your question what you are trying to do. It is clear that you are using a confusing nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. You should read this part of the MySQL manual.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html

The thing to keep in mind about SQL is that the hard part of any problem is precisely specifying the result set you want.

You've said, in your comments, that you want to show a detail listing of your inventory, that is, one row for each distinct item in inventory. But in that detail listing you want to show a cost that's averaged over all items in inventory of that make, model, and condition. This is tricky in SQL, because you're mixing apples (details) and orchards (averages).

To do that you need a subquery and a join.  The subquery works out your average costs.  It is this:

```
SELECT  m.name AS brand,
      opv.name AS model,
      opv.product_condition AS product_condition,
      AVG(opv.final_price + opv.overhead_cost) AS cost
 FROM ... the tables in your original ...
 JOIN ...     query in your question.
GROUP BY brand, model, product_condition
```

Then you need to treat this subquery as a virtual table, and join it to your main query like so.

```
SELECT  m.name AS brand,
      opv.name AS model,
      opv.product_condition AS product_condition,
      avg.cost,
      opv.product_color AS color
 FROM ... the tables in your original ...
 JOIN ...    query in your question.
 JOIN ...       in your question
 JOIN (
      SELECT  m.name AS brand,
            opv.name AS model,
            opv.product_condition AS product_condition,
            (AVG(opv.final_price + opv.overhead_cost)) AS cost
       FROM ...  the tables in your original
       JOIN ...     query in your question.
      GROUP BY brand, model, product_condition
      ) AS avg ON (     m.name=avg.name 
                   AND opv.name = avg.model
                   AND opv.product_condition = avg.product_condition)
```

Now, this looks like a horrible nasty query.  In a sense it is, because your specification sometimes calls for detail records and sometimes calls for averages.  But you should not worry about performance; it will be tolerably decent.  Notice that there's a `GROUP BY` clause in the subquery, because it is computing averages. But there is no such clause in the main query, because it is presenting detail records (individual items).

If you were just looking for aggregate results, you could have a couple of choices. If you were trying to show the average cost separately for items of different colors and conditions. In that case you want

```
 SELECT  m.name AS brand,
         opv.name AS model,
         opv.product_condition AS product_condition,
         AVG(opv.final_price + opv.overhead_cost) AS cost,
         opv.product_color AS color,
    FROM ...
    JOIN ... 
   GROUP BY brand, model, product_condition, color
```

But maybe you want to show average prices for items, regardless of color. In that case you want

```
 SELECT  m.name AS brand,
         opv.name AS model,
         opv.product_condition AS product_condition,
         AVG(opv.final_price + opv.overhead_cost) AS cost,
         GROUP_CONCAT (opv.product_color) AS color,
    FROM ...
    JOIN ... 
   GROUP BY brand, model, product_condition
```

Do you see how each item in the `SELECT ... GROUP BY` is mentioned both in `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`, or is subjected to a summary function (`SUM`, `GROUP_CONCAT`) in `SELECT`?  That's the standard way `GROUP BY` works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the useful link to the Documentation! Is Concat the only efficient way to achieve this? I do get what I want using CONCAT but I wanted to know if it's possible to view it in multiple rows like one row for black color and one for white one? And if I group by color then I don't get the average cost correctly.

Comment: @James, sorry, I don't understand your requirement. I find myself guessing. It seems you want to show a detail listing of your inventory, that is, one row for each distinct item in inventory. But in that detail listing you want to show a cost that's averaged over all items in inventory of that make, model, and condition.  Is that correct?

Comment: Your guess is correct, that is exactly what I want! I want to know if there is a way to achieve it and if it's possible to achieve it effectively?

Answer (score 0):

For any column that is not included in your `GROUP BY` you need to subject it to an aggregate function.

In your case, I think you mean to group by Brand, Model and Product_Condition, Average the cost and concatenate the colour.

```
SELECT
   m.name AS brand,
   opv.name AS model,
   opv.product_condition AS condition,
   (AVG(opv.final_price + opv.overhead_cost)) AS cost,
   CONCAT_WS(',', opv.product_color) AS color,
   COUNT(m.name) as quantity
   FROM `order` o
   JOIN order_veri AS ov
     ON o.order_id = ov.order_fk
   JOIN order_prod_veri AS opv
     ON ov.order_fk = opv.order_id
   JOIN product AS p
     ON opv.product_id = p.product_id
   JOIN manufacturer AS m
     ON p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
   GROUP  BY brand, model,
             product_condition
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is CONCAT the most efficient and the only way to achieve this? I was wondering if I can get it on seperate rows where there is difference in color like one row for Black color and the other one for White color but with the same average cost if the model name and condition is same.

Comment: Add colour to the `GROUP BY` clause (instead of using CONCAT) to get separate rows.

Comment: if I do that then I stop getting the average cost which is calculated if the model and condition is same regardless of it's color. So as long as Model and Condition is the same, it should then average the cost for them then.

Comment: That's right - so use the concatenation if you want the price irrespective of colour. If you want split rows by colour, but an average price that disregards colour, you'll end up using sub-queries which you may find sub-optimal (but possible if you really need to do it).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a row for each color (as well as your other group conditions) but an avg that ignores color, have to do it in 2 steps: get the average, then list the average for each color. You can do it with 2 queries, or by making the AVG a subquery.

I don't recommended the subquery as it is very inefficient. For any significant sized dataset or high volume application it will be slow. But if you prefer, here it is.

```
SELECT
  m.name AS brand,
  opv.name AS model,
  opv.product_condition AS condition,
  (
    SELECT AVG(opv.final_price + opv.overhead_cost) 
    FROM order_prod_veri as opv1
    JOIN product AS p1 ON opv1.product_id = p1.product_id
    JOIN manufacturer AS m1 ON p1.manufacturer_id = m1.manufacturer_id
    WHERE opv1.model = opv.model
      AND opv1.product_condition = opv.product_condition
      AND m1.name = m.name
    GROUP BY m1.brand, opv1.model, opv1.product_condition
  ) as cost
  opv.product_color AS color,
  COUNT(m.name) as quantity
FROM `order` o
JOIN order_veri AS ov ON o.order_id = ov.order_fk
JOIN order_prod_veri AS opv ON ov.order_fk = opv.order_id
JOIN product AS p ON opv.product_id = p.product_id
JOIN manufacturer AS m ON p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
GROUP  BY brand, model, product_condition, color
```

Comment: Perhaps recasting the suquery as a join would improve performance?

Comment: It'd still be inefficient, but perhaps not so bad. It's just all-around inefficient to do it in a single query. A 2-query solution would be much better IMHO. But sometimes you need what you need, and better can jump in a lake.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to answer my question! It was definitely in the right direction.